# Prove that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t).\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt \xrightarrow{\epsilon \to 0}f(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, dirac-delta

> Prove that, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in (L^1\cap C)(\mathbb{R})$,
>   $$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t).\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt \xrightarrow{\epsilon \to 0}f(x) $$

By substituting $u=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\epsilon}(t-x)$, we get $du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\epsilon}dt$ and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-u^2\right)du=\epsilon\\
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t).\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt-f(x)\\
&=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(t)-f(x))\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)du\\
\end{align*}
Suppose that $f$ is compactly supported. Let $[-a,a]$ be the compact support for $f$. Since $f$ is continuous, given $\eta > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|h| < \delta$, we have $|f(x+h)-f(x)| < \eta$. For all $\epsilon < \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\delta}{2a}$, we have $\left|\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x-x\right|=\frac{\epsilon |u|}{\sqrt{\pi}} < \frac{\epsilon 2a}{\sqrt{\pi}} < \delta$ giving us $\left|f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right|< \eta$. Hence, for all $\epsilon < \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\delta}{2a}$
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t).\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt-f(x)\right|&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\right|\exp\left(-u^2\right)du\\
&\le\eta\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(-u^2)du=\eta\\
\end{align*}
Now, since compactly supported functions are dense in $L^1$, for any function $f \in L^1$, there exists a compactly supported function $h $ such that $\|f-h\|_1 < \frac{\eta\sqrt{\pi}}{3}$. Therefore,

$$\left|\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t).\exp\left(\frac{-\pi(x-t)^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)dt-f(x)\right|$$
$$\le
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-h\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)\right)\right|\exp\left(-u^2\right)du$$
$$+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\left(h\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-h(x)\right)\right|\exp(-u^2)du+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|h(x)-f(x)|\exp(-u^2)$$

I can make the first two integrals small. I am not able to make the third integral small. I am yet to use that $f$ is continuous. There is a way to do this problem using Dominated Convergence Theorem. I don't want to do that.

> (Using Hint)

Let $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Let $E_n=[-n,n]$. Then $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $\mathbb{R}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. Therefore $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|d\mu=\lim_
{n \to \infty}\int_{E_n}|f|d\mu$$ Let $\eta \gt 0$. Then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$, we have $$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|d\mu-\int_{E_n}|g|d\mu\right|\lt \eta \implies \left|\int_{|x| \gt n}|g(x)|d\mu \right| \lt \eta$$ 
Since $f, e^{-u^{2}} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$, we have $\int_{|u| \gt n}|f(u)|du \lt \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\eta}{4}$ and $\int_{|u| \gt n}e^{-u^2}du \lt \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\eta}{4|f(x)|}$. `

Now $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{|u| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)du+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{|u| \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)du$$
Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that whenever $|h| \lt \delta$, we have $|f(x+h)-f(x)| \lt \frac{\eta}{2}$.
Thus, for $\epsilon \lt \pi\delta^2$, whenever $|u| \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}, |x+u\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}-x| \lt \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{\pi} \lt \delta$ and 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left|\int_{|u| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)du\right|\\&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{|u| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}\left|\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\right|\exp\left(-u^2\right)du\\
&\le \frac{\eta}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{|u| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}e^{-u^2}du&(\text{ using continuity of f})\\
&\lt \frac{\eta}{2}\\
\end{align*}
For $\epsilon \lt \frac{1}{n_0^2}, |u| \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} \gt n_0$ and $\left\{|u| \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right\} \subset \{|u| \gt n_0\}$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left|\int_{|u| \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)\right|du\\ &\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{|u| \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}\left|f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)\right|du
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}|f(x)|\int_{|u| \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}e^{-u^2}du\\
&\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{|u| \gt n_0}\left|f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)\right|du
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}|f(x)|\int_{|u| \gt n_0}e^{-u^2}du\\
&\le \frac{\eta
}{2}\\
\end{align*}
Thus, for $\epsilon \lt \min\{\pi\delta^2,\frac{1}{n_0^2}\}$, we have the claim.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What you need the so-called continuity of translates of $L^{1}$ functions. See Theorem 9.5 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (third edition). Once you split the integral into , say $(-N,N)$ and its complement and apply the theorem on the first part you can easily complete the proof.

Comment: On the first part as in? You mean the last part?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't understand. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Yes, I meant the last part.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you elaborate your suggestion?

Comment: Assume first that f is also bounded. On $\{u:|u|>N\}$ pull out the bound for $|f(\frac {u \epsilon} {\sqrt{ \pi}}-f(x)|$. On $\{u:|u|\leq N\}$ use uniform continuity of f. For the general case approximate f by a bounded continuous  $L^{1}$ function in the $L^{1}$ norm. The standard inequality $||f*g||_1 \leq ||f||_1 ||g_1||$ can be used to complete the proof. ( I did not use continuity of translates in this proof).

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem:** Let $g\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb R)$ with $\int_{\mathbb R} g(x) dx = 1$. Then $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \tfrac 1\epsilon g\big(\tfrac x\epsilon\big) = \delta(x)$

So in fact your integral is nothing but the convolution

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  f* g_\epsilon = f * \delta = f$$

with $g(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$. A proof of the theorem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083721/proof-on-delta-sequences).

Comment: Can it done by the way I have proceeded?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Probably, but I think that would just unnecessarily complicate things. Any proof you try to do would  have to somewhat resemble the proof of the above, but only for 1 special choice of $g$. The $u$ substitution you did is the correct thing to do, but then instead of the compact support approximation, try splitting the integral $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(f\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\pi}}u+x\right)-f(x)\right)\exp\left(-u^2\right)du$$ into 2 parts: one for which $\epsilon u$ is small and one for which it is large and then use $f\in L^1\cap C$ to show both vanish.

Comment: How would I take care of the part where it is large?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam I will just give you the hint, try $|u|\le 1/\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Have a look at the answer now

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Yes, that's basically it.